# Are SSL and Kerberos compatible to each other on Hive Server?

Tags: ssl, hive, kerberos

My Hive server is SSL as well as Kerberos enabled. But when I try to connect to hiverserver2 via beeline using following command:

```
*!connect jdbc:hive2://**hostnameOfServer**:10000/hive;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=**keystorePath**;trustStorePassword=**passwordfor keystore**;principal=**Kerberos hive principal** **database username** **database password** org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver*
```

I get following error :

> *Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:  jdbc:hive2://**hostnameOfServer**:10000/hive;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=**keystorePath**;trustStorePassword=**passwordfor
>   keystore**;principal=**Kerberos hive principal** **database username**
>   **database password** org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver: Invalid status 21 (state=08S01,code=0)*

Also I tried using following command on beeline:

```
jdbc:hive2://**hostnameOfServer**:10000/hive;principal=**Kerberos hive principal**?transportMode=https;httpPath=cliservice;auth=kerberos;sasl.qop=auth.
```

But got same error.

Are ssl and kerberos compatible to each other?

Comment: Side note: with Kerberos authentication, `user` and `password` args are ignored. You must either *(a)* have a valid Kerberos ticket in the default ticket cache or *(b)* provide the raw JAAS config to define how to create a ticket automatically (via Java system properties).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is compatible from version Hive-2.0.0. Check the below JIRA task for more information

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14019

Comment: That's for "binary" protocol (the default one). Before that, you could switch to HTTP protocol to have both SSL and Kerberos.